# Debbuging preflight request on Chrome95 or firefox94

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, axios, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to debug the `preflight` request to know it works well.

So, I made request by `axios` with custom header

```
  var config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "triggering/preflight"
    }
  }
  axios.get(http://www.example.com/api/`,config)
    .then((res)=> {
      console.log("API work");
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log("API NG");
      console.log(err);
  });
```

It is supposed to be used with preflight request.

However in both on Chrome and on Firefox, There is only `POST` request in dev tools network tab.

`OPTIONS` request is not shown.

I googled around and some chrome version(76~) doesn't show preflight.

[enter link description here](https://newbedev.com/chrome-not-showing-options-requests-in-network-tab)

I am not sure my version(95) is the same or not, but on firefox there is no `OPTIONS` shown too.

Is there the most basic way to check if preflight works ??